# How to use Glimpse ADO with SqlHelper class

Tags: glimpse

We have used SqlHelper class to perform all ADO related operations:

SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "SP_NAME",parameters);

I have installed Glimpse ADO but SQL tab is disabled. From documentation I came to know how it builds the wrapper.

Can you please let me know is there any way how to use it with SqlHelper class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're helper should create the connection via `DbProviderFactory` and then it will automatically work.

If you can't use that for some reason, [then check out the instructions on how to manually wire up Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Manual-ADO-Integration).

Comment: When I try to create the connection I am getting "Unable to cast object of type 'Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType.GlimpseDbConnection' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'."

Comment: I have created a SqlConnection object with GlimpseDbConnection.InnerConnection and trying to pass it in my SqlHelper class. But Sql tab is not enabled. Isn't it the correct way of doing it ?

Comment: Any how I ended up with manually wiring up Glimpse. Thanks @nikmd23